# Boot ubuntu from grub if can't find files

Tags: boot, grub2, filesystem

I have an issue with an old notebook at boot. If I choose the load Ubuntu then it goes to `(initramfs)` console, so I tried to boot up from grub, because I can't run even `sudo fsck` because it says `sudo not found`, so I tried to load ubuntu fro grub [as I read here](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux%20). But after boot I also got `(initramfs)` console with some errors:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/local-bootom ... done.
done.
Begin: Runing /scipts/init-bottom ..mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
done.
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such fiule or directory
Target filesystem doesen't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

How can I boot my system? How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think it's just `fsck` with no `sudo`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen also `/bin/sh: fsck: not found`